# Trying to import AWS Amplify iOS SDK along with AWS AppSync

Tags: ios, swift, aws-amplify, aws-appsync

I've a project that use AWS AppSync iOS SDK: https://github.com/awslabs/aws-mobile-appsync-sdk-ios .
I want to migrate AWS Amplify: https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-swift .

I've imported AWS AppSync using SPM.

The first conflict was SQlite.Swift (different version), I forked the AWS AppSync and updated to use the latest version.

Now, I'm tying to import AWS Amplify using SPM and having an errors on 'multiple product named'.

[image: SPM Image with errors]

Image: https://imageupload.io/ib/hjBlWeCHt5nyt8l_1695273595.png

How to make a project with both of them live together?

Comment: Image not found

Comment: I've edited and reuploaded the image.

Comment: Could be some internal version conflict issue between the two packages, did you select all the frameworks inside Amplify to add to your project?